# How to use UserDefinedType(UDT) with Spring Data Cassandra for List<UDT>

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, user-defined-types, spring-data-cassandra

I have created a UDT named widgetData in cql for which i have a corresponding POJO class named widgetData. I want to use this in another domain POJO class as List. What kind of annotation should be used to do so?

```
@Table("dashboardManagement")
public class Dashboard implements Serializable {

    @Column("dashboardState")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UDT, userTypeName = "widgetData")
    private List<widgetData> dashboardState;
....
```

The above code does not work.
Do I have to write a seperate userTypeResolver for this?

Comment: Care to share what's not working (error message, what actually happens) and the code of your `widgetData` class?

Comment: Hi, did you find a sollution on this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a little old, but I have made this work.

Basically, I had a user profile with an address UDT, and that UDT had its own POJOs/entity classes.  The UDT address entity class used the `@UserDefinedType` annotation:

```
@UserDefinedType("address")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1817053316281666003L;

    @Column("mailto_name")
    private String mailtoName;
    private String street;
    private String street2;
    private String city;
...
```

The user entity utilized the Address UDT entity:

```
@Table("user")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4067531918643498429L;

    @PrimaryKey("user_id")
    private UUID userId;
    @Column("user_email")
    private String userEmail;
    @Column("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column("addresses")
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
    ...
```

Then, it was a simple matter to map a user's address data to a `UserEntity` object (`userE` below) and save it with standard repository methods.

```
// save to DB
userRepo.save(userE);
```

You can find everything built to support the User services here: https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-ecommerce-app/blob/main/backend/src/main/java/com/datastax/tutorials/service/user/

So I would say to have a look at the class for the `widgetData` object, make sure it's using the `@UserDefinedType` annotation, and mark the column using the `@Column` annotation in the `Dashboard` class (basically, get rid of the `@CassandraType`):

```
@Column("dashboardState")
private List<WidgetData> dashboardState;
```