# Why can Spring Data not find suitable converter for UDT?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I defined a UDT POJO class as follows

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@UserDefinedType("address_type")
public class Address {
    
@Column("address_line")
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String addressLine;
@Column("postal_code")
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String postalCode;
@Column
@CassandraType(type = Name.TEXT)
private String city;

}
```

and also added this UDT  definition on my keyspace for cassandra. My Entity with which I defined my UDT fields is

```
@Table("customer_model")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomerModel {

@PrimaryKey
private Integer id ;

@Column("company_name")
private String companyName;

@Column("company_email")
private String companyEmail;

@Column("tax_id")
private String taxId;

@Column("billing_address")
@CassandraType(type = Name.UDT,userTypeName = "address_type")
private Address billingAddress;

@CassandraType(userTypeName = "address_type", type = Name.UDT)
@Column("shipping_address")
private Address shippingAddress;
 }
```

When I try to make basic CRUD operations I get following Exception ,

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [models.udt.Address] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]
```

I tried to add Custom Converter implementations to no avail. How to make spring find suitable converters for my POJO UDT to Cssandra UDT type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar problem was encountered here. [How-to-use-userdefinedtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030698/how-to-use-userdefinedtypeudt-with-spring-data-cassandra-for-listudt) Somehow when you annotate your UDT POJO with `@UserDefinedType` , there is no need to annotate them again with `@CassandraType` while using them as entity class fields.